# QtCreator: static library but still asking for DLL

Tags: qt, static-libraries, qt-creator

I'm using QtCreator and I got two projects, each with an own PRO file.

The Viewer is a normal Qt app.
The other one, let's call it Utilities, is supposed to be a static library which is used in the Viewer.

However when I compile and run the Viewer (everything compiles fine), I get an error message telling me Utilities.dll was not found.

This is the first part of the PRO-file for Utilities:

```
QT       -= core gui

TARGET = Utilities
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib warn_on $$(QMAKESPEC)
```

Shouldn't it work that way? 
 

Why is it compiling the Utilities.a file fine but asking me for the DLL at runtime? It's supposed to be a static library :(

 Since I did not specify some needed libraries in Utilities.pro, it apparently did not link as you'd expect for a static library.

My platform is W7-x64, latest Qt SDK and MingW 4.4 bundled with it.
Hope anyone can help :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `CONFIG += staticlib` request *your* target library to be a static lib not the entire dependency chain ... I am pretty sure your `.a` lib will require `mingw` dlls to run ...

If you want to reduce dependencies try the `MSVC` tool chain (Qt provide pre-compiled package for that) you will end with one or two mandatory dll dependencies. Or you can link again static `mingw` SDK (you will probably have to build it your-self ...).